# Function executes differently on two diffrent element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Not sure why I'm getting an error

> Cannot read property ‘val’ of undefined

on Slider change unlike button  onClick

App.js

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
   val: 0,
 }
  this.handelChange = this.handelChange.bind(this)
}

handelChange() {
  let tmp = this.state.val
}

render() {
  return(
    <div>
      <Button onClick = {this.handelChange} />
      <CustomSlider onChange= {this.handelChange} />
    </div>  
  )
}
```

Slider.js

```
import React from "react";
import Tooltip from "rc-tooltip";
import Slider, { Range } from "rc-slider";

const Handle = Slider.Handle;

const handle = props => {
   const { value, dragging, index, ...restProps } = props;
   return (
      <Tooltip
         prefixCls="rc-slider-tooltip"
         overlay={value}
         visible={dragging}
         placement="top"
         key={index}
      >
         <Handle value={value} {...restProps} />
      </Tooltip>
   );
};

const Slider = props => {
   return (
      <div>
         <div style={{ width: 300, margin: 30 }}>
            <p>{this.props.title}</p>
            <Slider min={0} max={10} defaultValue={5} onChange={props.onChange} handle={handle}/>
         </div>
      </div>
   );
};

export default Slider;
```

handelChange executes without an error on button click. However, onChange of slider it gives an error `Cannot read property ‘val’ of undefined`. How come the same function does not executes the same on two different elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind `handelChange` to `this` or convert `handelChange` into an arrow function.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handelChange = this.handelChange.bind(this)
  }
```

Comment: Hey, also I notice that you are shallowing your components (Two components with the same name), I'm not sure if that is what generates the error though, try changing the name of your component to CustomSlider instead.